# Knockout click binding how to get Array of the "current item"?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

```
Short Example:
<div data-bind="foreach: firstArray">
  <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
  <input type="checkbox"  data-bind="click: $parent.delete"/>
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: secArray">
  <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
  <input type="checkbox"  data-bind="click: $parent.delete"/>
</div>

 [...]
 self.firstArray = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.delete = function (item, event) {
        self.firstArray.remove(item);
 }
 [...]
```

Problem: I have 2 Arrays which both use the same function in which I want to know where the item is coming from (from first or secArray).

Comment: Why don't you create two functions: removeFromFirst, removeFromSecond?

Comment: You could simply pass the parent as a parameter to your delete function.

Comment: I thought it should be posible to eigther pass the Array to the function or do something like item.parent.remove(item) that would be prettier then creating to functions. Also i gonna have that problem more often in my code

Comment: I tried to pass it to my function :) but with no success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to pass the array to your delete function.
Like:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: firstArray">
  <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
  <input type="checkbox"  data-bind="click: $parent.delete.bind($data, $parent.firstArray)"/>
</div>
```

And your viewmodel should know that you passed the function and the `this` is your current item.

```
self.firstArray = ko.observableArray([]);
self.delete = function (array) {
    array.remove(this);
}
```

You can read more on the click binding [here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html). It states there how to pass parameters.

Comment: Thanks did it a bit diffrent data-bind="click: function (data) { $parent.delete($parent.firstArray, data) }" result is the same :) before i just passed a string this is way better :)

Comment: No problem, it's just own preferences, I don't like to clutter my htmls :D

Comment: @JSTW1212 `$parent.delete.bind($parent.firstArray)` would work the same.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you have two functions?

```
<div data-bind="foreach: firstArray">
  <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
  <input type="checkbox"  data-bind="click: $parent.deleteFromFirst"/>
</div>
<div data-bind="foreach: secArray">
  <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
  <input type="checkbox"  data-bind="click: $parent.deleteFromSecond"/>
</div>

 [...]
 self.firstArray = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.deleteFromFirst = function (item, event) {
        self.firstArray.remove(item);
 }
 self.secArray = ko.observableArray([]);
 self.deleteFromSecond = function (item, event) {
        self.secArray.remove(item);
 }
 [...]
```